# Outlook fails to start because MSVCR80.dll is missing?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I get an error when start Outlook as below screenshot:

[image]

Please help if you know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The "MSVCR80.dll is missing" error in Microsoft Outlook generally means that an add-in or plugin you've installed has created it's own `outlook.exe.manifest` file in the Outlook installation directory and got it wrong.

Removing this file should resolve your issue.

To remove the manifest file, browse to the installation location of Microsoft Outlook. By default this will be as below;

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12
```

Or, on a 64 bit version of Windows/32 bit version of Office this would be;

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12
```

Find the `outlook.exe.manifest` file and delete it.

Once this file has been deleted you will need to repair your Microsoft Office installation to re-create the correct manifest file. You can do this by running Microsoft Office Diagnostics from the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

Start in safe mode with `outlook.exe /safe` in the Start > Run menu, and disable your add-ins one at a time until you find out which one is causing it.

([Source.](http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Office-2007-Outlook-reports-MSVCR80-DLL-Missing-work--ftopict943628.html))

Comment: @Potter: I follow your suggestion but run your command results in the same error message. Any idea for me?

Comment: Did you look at the other steps in the Source link I posted? There's talk of deleting a manifest file as well, which might require digging on your part.

Comment: I'm removing and to reinstall everything of office. I'll talk back with you when I'm done. Thank you Randolph.

Comment: Good luck. I don't think it'll work though, but if it does, that's good.

Comment: @Potter: Outlook on my PC works well before I update it by following Windows Auto Update. Now the error reappear. I have tried to remove the manifest file.

Comment: Which update broke it?

Comment: @Potter: I have given up and restore my OS, reinstall Office. Thank you for your great help anyway. I guess the problem is all about the confliction vetween Office version and Windows x86 vs x64.

Comment: Perhaps so. Well, hopefully you've sorted it out. Put your solution in its own answer, and accept it, so that the question can be closed.